# Ubuntu 21.04 dual boot on iMac BigSur Wireless Device not supported

Tags: networking, wireless

I have Ubuntu 21.04 and MacOS BigSur setup to dual boot.  Using `ioreg -l | grep RequestedFiles`, I have obtained my MacOS driver information.

```
"RequestedFiles" = ({
"Firmware"="C-4364__s-B2/nihau.trx",
"TxCap"="C-4364__s-B2/nihau-X0.txcb",
"Regulatory"="C-4364__s-B2/nihau-X0.clmb","NVRAM"="C-4364__s-B2/P-nihau-X0_M-HRPN_V-m__m-7.7.txt"})'
```

I copied these files and renamed them accordingly in my Ubuntu install `brcmfmac4364-pcie.bin`, `brcmfmac4364-pcie.clm_blob`, `brcmfmac4364-pcie.Apple Inc.-iMac,2.txt`.

I run `sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac && sudo modprobe brcmfmac` to reload the modules but I can see the failure to load of -2.  When I run `journalctl -k --grep=brcmfmac`

From all of the supported firmware lists I can find, I don't see BCM4363 listed or the ID 14e4:4464.  I believe my hardware is new enough it isn't in the included drivers.  Has anyone else figure out how to get their Wi-Fi working?

Comment: Your device is, indeed, covered by the driver brcmfmac. Let's see what's going wrong. Please edit your question to show the *complete* result of this terminal command: `sudo modprobe brcmfmac && sudo dmesg | grep brcm` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the command you gave me was really helpful. I did a little more work on my own.  I found on this site (https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-activate-wifi-on-bcm4364-using-brcmfac-driver-firmware/) that they used a different firmware.  Most of my understanding of what to do came from here (https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi/).  I just didn't use the firmware from my own machine.  I also had to follow the instructions at the bottom to get WPS2 to work.

Here is how I installed my firmware:

wget https://packages.aunali1.com/apple/wifi-fw/18G2022/C-4364__s-B2/kauai.trx
sudo cp kauai.trx /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie.bin

wget https://packages.aunali1.com/apple/wifi-fw/18G2022/C-4364__s-B2/nihau-X0.clmb
sudo cp nihau-X0.clmb
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie.clm_blob

wget https://packages.aunali1.com/apple/wifi-fw/18G2022/C-4364__s-B2/P-nihau-X0_M-HRPN_V-m__m-7.7.txt
sudo cp P-nihau-X0_M-HRPN_V-m__m-7.7.txt /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie.Apple\ Inc.-iMac19,2.txt

Then I rebooted.

Thanks so much for your help chili555.  I was just stuck and needed a tip to get over the hump.